# Schengen Visa for Austria and Germany

Tags: visas, schengen

Please advise where do i need transit visa in Europe if am holding Indian passport & US visa and flying from Washington to Delhi with 2 stops anywhere in the Europe.
For Exp: i am going to Delhi to Washington via Vienna, Austria (layover is only for 4 hours 20 minutes) then fly back from Detroit to Delhi via Frankfurt, Germany FRA (layover is only for 2 hours 40 minutes) and Vienna, Austria VIE (layover is only for 3 hours)

Comment: Your question is very unclear, are you flying from Washington to Delhi or the other way around? When are you flying to or from Detroit? And you only have one stop in Europe/the Schengen area in one case but two stops in the other case, is that correct?

Comment: Hi Sonal. You have already asked this question here: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50280/schengen-transit-visa. If you want to add more information, please edit the original question, instead of creating a new one.